# Why is the Facebook Access Log showing more than it should?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the server-side SDK to access Facebook Authentication.

After authorizing my app - even with the included example.php, I can go to [App Privacy](http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications) in settings then click on the app, then `See Details` in the `Last data access` section

And the dialog shows:

> My App accessed the following information on your behalf:
>
> Basic Information - Today
>
> Likes, Music, TV, Movies, Books, Quotes, About Me, Hometown, Current City, Education History and Work History - Today
>
> My Friends' Current Cities - Today

All I really need from the authentication is the userid and possibly name... I don't care about any other personal info. And yet even the example.php which is really basic seems to be requesting a lot.

Is there another way to authenticate without Facebook thinking I pulled all this data? I don't want users to be concerned about excessive data pulling when I'm not even pulling it.

The Stack Exchange authentication does not have this issue. It might be an issue in the PHP SDK?

Comment: Just remove the req_perms part of the example code. If you don't specify any additional permissions, you will only get basic_permission by default. Good luck

Comment: If you go to the [example.php source](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) you'll see that there are no `req_perms`. Please let me know if I'm mistaken.

Comment: This is normal I suppose, no need to worry.

Comment: If you go to other apps, their data access doesn't include things like "My Friends' Current Cities"

Comment: It seems that every application says the same thing, no matter the permissions you ask. That's logical I suppose, because even with the basic permission you can access all the user connections, and if the user has explicitly made it public you will get data back, if not you get empty array.

Comment: As ifaour said, no need to worry, and nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional entries in the app access log are created for requests to the /me-object without a [fields-parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). So instead of accessing /me?access_token=xxx use /me?fields=id,name,...&access_token=...

Please note that the access log is not deleted when you remove an application. This may be quite confusing during testing because you will see old entries.